# Jenkins CI Plugin run on slave

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins-plugins

I am developing a plugin for the Jenkins CI. Now i get a problem when the plugin is running on a slave machine. On the slave I need logging to the master, passing parameters from the master and launching processes on the slave. Therefore I wrote this code:

```
private static class LauncherCallable implements FilePath.FileCallable<String>
{

private BuildListener listener;
private SetupConfig config;
private String nsisVersion;
private Launcher launcher;

public LauncherCallable(BuildListener listener, SetupConfig config, String nsisVersion, Launcher launcher)
{
  this.listener = listener;
  this.config = config;
  this.nsisVersion = nsisVersion;
  this.launcher = launcher;
}

@Override
public String invoke(File file, VirtualChannel vc) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
  try
  {
    final RemoteOutputStream ros = new RemoteOutputStream(listener.getLogger());

    ScriptGenerator scriptGenerator = new ScriptGenerator(config);

    listener.getLogger().println("Downloading NSIS...");
    String nsisPath = Downloader.getNsisPath(listener, nsisVersion);

    listener.getLogger().println("Derteming version from AssembyInfo...");
    String assemblyVersion = AssemblyVersionParser.determineVersion(new File(file + "/" + config.getAssemblyInfoPath()));
    listener.getLogger().println(" -> Version: " + assemblyVersion);

    listener.getLogger().println("Generating .nsi file...");
    String nsiString = scriptGenerator.generateScript();
    nsiString = nsiString.replace("$VERSION", assemblyVersion);

    listener.getLogger().println("Checking NSIS installation...");

    File nsisExecutable = new File(new File(nsisPath).getAbsolutePath() + "/makensis.exe");
    if (!nsisExecutable.exists())
      throw new Exception("Could not find NSIS executable: " + nsisExecutable);

    listener.getLogger().println("Writing .nsi file...");
    String scriptGuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    File scriptFile = new File(file + "/" + scriptGuid + ".nsi");
    PrintStream scriptOutStream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(scriptFile, false));
    scriptOutStream.print(nsiString);
    scriptOutStream.close();

    listener.getLogger().println("Launching NSIS...");
    ProcStarter ps = launcher.new ProcStarter();
    ArgumentListBuilder command = new ArgumentListBuilder();
    command.addTokenized(nsisExecutable.toString() + " " + scriptFile.getAbsolutePath());
    ps.cmds(command); //.stdout(listener)
    Proc proc = launcher.launch(ps);
    int nsisReturn = proc.join();
    listener.getLogger().println("NSIS returned: " + nsisReturn);

    listener.getLogger().println("Deleting temp file...");
    if (!scriptFile.delete())
      throw new Exception("Could not delete script file " + scriptFile.getAbsolutePath() + " !");

    return (nsisReturn == 0) ? "SUCCESS" : "FAIL";
  } catch (Exception ex)
  {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    ex.printStackTrace(listener.getLogger());
    return "FAIL";
  }
}

@Override
public void checkRoles(RoleChecker rc) throws SecurityException
{
}
}
```

The callable is run by this code in the plugin on the master:

```
build.getWorkspace().act(fc);
```

By doing this I get the following Exception:

```
java.io.IOException: remote file operation failed: C:\\[...] at hudson.remoting.Channel@4cf8aa7c:CIAgent:
java.io.IOException: Unable to serialize hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper@3b712782
  at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:987)
  at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:969)
  at jenkinsnsis.JenkinsNsisPlugin.NsisPlugin.perform(NsisPlugin.java:136)
  at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
  at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779‌​)
  at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
  at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
  at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:537)
  at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
  at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
  at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
  at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:408)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to serialize hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper@3b712782
  at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.serialize(UserRequest.java:169)
  at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.<init>(UserRequest.java:63)
  at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:776)
  at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:980)
  ... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
  ...
```

What am I doing wrong? Unfortunately I did not find any exaples using the log and starting processes. Thank you!

Comment: I edited the stacktrace into the question; you can delete the comments :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to pass your `FileCallable` object to the remote machine, Jenkins needs to be able to serialise the entire object.  This means that all fields need to implement `java.io.Serializable`.

In this case, I would guess that your `SetupConfig` type is not serialisable.

If you own this type and can mark it as `Serializable`, and ensure that all its fields can be serialised, then that should fix it.  If this is a third-party class, you will likely need to construct the `SetupConfig` instance within the `invoke` method.

---

**Edit:** Now that you've posted the full stacktrace, we can see that in fact `Launcher` is the class that cannot be serialised (`java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher`).

You don't need to pass in `Launcher` to your callable — you can use `ArgumentListBuilder` as you are just now, but you can use [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) rather than `ProcStarter` to execute NSIS.

(Everything inside the `invoke` method is already [running on the remote machine](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/FilePath.FileCallable.html#invoke), so you don't need to do anything special).

For example:

```
ArgumentListBuilder args = ...;
ProcessBuilder proc = new ProcessBuilder(args.toList());
proc.start().waitFor();
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. The SetupConfig is a custom class, right. I already added Serializable to this class and all other custom classes it uses.

Comment: @C.M. Ok, if you're still having the problem, assuming `fc` is an instance of `LauncherCallable`, you probably need to show more of the `unable to serialize` stacktrace. Is `CIAgent` a class involved?

Comment: CIAgent is the name of the slave. I've added ste stack trace as a comment on my initial question. Thanks already for your help!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now it seems to work! I don't get any serializable errors anymore! Great! ;-) My only problem now is that makensis.exe is not run properly. I get the following error:

Comment: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\...\Downloads\nsis_download\nsis-2.42\makensis.exe C:\Users\...\Downloads\workspace\NsisTest\5254581d-2843-4746-ac8c-06b01544b28c.nsi": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Why does he want to work in the Downloads folder?
I start process creation by doing this:
ArgumentListBuilder args = new ArgumentListBuilder(nsisExecutable.toString() + " " + scriptFile.getAbsolutePath());

The files are downloaded to the Jenkins installation folder. I don't do anything in the Downloads folder...

Comment: On the live system it is:
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Jenkins\nsis_download\nsis-2.46\makensis.exe C:\Jenkins\workspace\...\d4c28162-cdbc-4fb3-9fa8-b94f57b149f3.nsi": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

But the file is present on the slave... Does he maybe try to execute this on the master?